# Conditionally show/hide Drupal Display suite fields

Tags: php, drupal

I have programmatically created 2 custom Display Suite fields (abc1 and abc2) for a content type xyz of type node.

I can see the fields on Manage Display for xyz but I need to show 1 custom field and hide the other depending on a few conditions.

I tried to do this in preprocess_fields in template.php with no luck. Where would be the best place to render the fields based on conditional checks?

Answer (score -1):

Try with `hook_entity_view_alter();` user `$build` referenced, to change the `#access` key value of each field. i.e. this is example to set all fields visible, using `#access` key value ( boolean )

```
function yourmodule_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type){
        global $node; 

            foreach($build as $key => $item){
                if(strstr($key, 'field')){
                    $build[$key]['#access'] = true;
                }
            }


     }
```